# PHP - invoking variables from inside eval() function

Tags: php, mysql, eval

At first, I know that using `eval()` is a bad choice,
but my team already built an application based on templates stored in a database.
I am appointed to edit a template that should use a variable in the script outside the `eval()` function.
Here is an code example:

template.php

```
function template($arg)
{
   if($arg == "show")
   {
       $template = str_replace("\\'", "'", addslashes($row['template']));
   }
return $template;
}
```

`$row['template'] = "this is template from database that shows {$row[data]}";`

`$row[data] = {$variable};`

show.php

```
<?php
  include 'template.php'
  $variable = "thisShouldAppear";
  eval("\$var = \"".template("show")."\";");
  echo $var;
?>
```

The output in show.php is:

`{$variable}`

And it's supposed to show:

> thisShouldAppear

### NOTE:

If I assign the variable from outside the database it works but I'm limited to including it from the template inside the database.

> Example:

```
<?php
  include 'template.php'
  $variable = "thisShouldAppear";
  $row[data] = "{$variable}";
  eval("\$var = \"".template("show")."\";");
  echo $var;
?>
```

In this case it works , but the aim is to have the value from the template not from the script.

Any help would be extremely appreciated, for I'm running out of schedule.
Thank you.

Comment: In your function `template($arg)`, `$row` is undefined.

Comment: It is defined in the actual script, I only put the essencial code here in the post to make it short

Comment: I recognize that you've made a attempt at showing the least amount of code possible, but it looks like you've made it harder to understand in the process. Here's a few tips to improve this: 1). Remove the `include` and instead embed the `template()` definition in the show.php 2) `$row` not being in scope of `template()` makes it hard to understand what you're code is actually doing. Can it be mocked? 3) "The output in show.php is:{$variable}" I kind of don't believe this. `$row['data']` is never referenced in your MVCE. 4) You've mentioned a database, but I don't see anything about a database?

Comment: i'm the OP. @HPierce i know that the people who are viewing my question are programmers and they understand it, that's why i ,made it clear and trimmed some parts and explained them instead. <br> second, in the last example when I said itworks, if I change from `$row['data'] = "{$variable"};` to `$row["data"] = $_GET["input"];` and the last GET input will be `{"$variable"}` it doesn't execute, so it executes only the pre declared variables and not the user input, you can simulate the code and see what happens.